# How to make nested associative array from two other arrays with PHP or Laravel functions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to make an array that looks like this:

```
$array = [
      'value_1' => [
        'key' => 'name_1'
      ],
      'value_2' => [
        'key' => 'name_2'
      ]
    ];
```

From two different array that look like this:

`$array_two=['value_1', 'value_2'];`
`$array_three=['name_1', 'name_2'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array_two = ['value_1', 'value_2'];
$array_three = ['name_1', 'name_2'];

$array = array_combine($array_two, array_map(function ($val) {
    return ['key' => $val];
}, $array_three));

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thank you man!! You are the best!!! Is there a way to avoid error like `array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements` if `$array_three` has more elements?

Comment: there is... but how should the result look like? seems to make no sense!?